# Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:testapp/cart.dart';
import 'package:testapp/cart_item.dart';

class CartScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context);
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(
      'Cart Screen',
      style:
          TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
    ),
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ListView.builder(
          itemCount: cart.items.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => CartPdt(
              cart.items.values.toList()[i].id,
              cart.items.keys.toList()[i],
              cart.items.values.toList()[i].price,
              cart.items.values.toList()[i].quantity,
              cart.items.values.toList()[i].name)),
      FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text(
            'CHECKOUT',
            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFD1845A), fontSize: 18.0),
          ))
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

why do i get an error "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 5 found. Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments" . Anyone can help me about this stuff?

Comment: Show me your `CartPdt` implementation

Answer (score 0):

`CartPdt` is expecting named arguments (as defined in the `CartPdt` class with your parameters surrounded by curly braces `{}`). I'm assuming the names will be something like `id, key, price, quantity, name`.

Update your instantiation of the `CartPdt` class to this

```dart
CartPdt(
    id: cart.items.values.toList()[i].id,
    key: cart.items.keys.toList()[i],
    price: cart.items.values.toList()[i].price,
    quantity: cart.items.values.toList()[i].quantity,
    name: cart.items.values.toList()[i].name))
```

Comment: i just posted my cartPdt code...thanks in advance for your help

Comment: anyways, this comment of yours works!! Thank you!!!

Comment: Thanks @airaclaveria. Instead of updating your post using an Answer please just edit your original post with more information. Also, if my answer helped you out please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

here is my CartPdt code...

'''
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class CartPdt extends StatelessWidget {
 final String id;
 final String productId;
 final double price;
 final int quantity;
 final String name;

 CartPdt ({this.id, this.productId, this.price, this.quantity, this.name});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Card(
   child: ListTile(
    leading: CircleAvatar(
      child: FittedBox(
        child: Text('Php$price'),
      ),
    ),
    title: Text(name),
    subtitle: Text('Total: Php${(price * quantity)}'),
    trailing: Text('$quantity x'),
  ),
);
```

}
}
'''